# pylint 1.6.3 reports E1101(no-member) for xml

Tags: python, pylint

We are using the [ElementTree library](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) in our project. This comes from the standard library, but for some reason pylint chokes on it. It always reports an E1101 on any reference on an ElementTree object. Here is a sample bit of code to demonstrate this:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

test = ET.parse('test.xml')
config = test.find('.//configuration')
print(config)

for role in config.findall('.//role'):
    print(role)
```

The output from pylint always throws an E1101:

```
$ pylint --rcfile=pylint.cfg -E test.py
************* Module orion-scripts.test
E:  7,12: Instance of 'int' has no 'findall' member (no-member)
```

But the program runs just fine:

```
$ python test.py
<Element 'role' at 0x1052dfe50>
<Element 'configuration' at 0x1052dfe10>
```

I found a number of solutions to similar problems, but so far none have worked for this one. I've tried:

- Setting an ignored class with `ignored-classes=xml.etree.ElementTree`
- Setting it as a generated member with `generated-members=ET`
- Allowing any extension to run with `unsafe-load-any-extension=yes`

Nothing has worked and I'm currently just ignoring E1101 messages. However, this is a really bad option and I would much prefer to just ignore this particular class. If it helps, this is the version info for pylint:

```
$ pylint --version
No config file found, using default configuration
pylint 1.6.3, 
astroid 1.4.7
Python 2.7.11 (default, Jan 22 2016, 08:28:37) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)]
```